# How to change default JDBC driver of Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an old Oracle 9i r2 database. The last JDBC driver that I managed to make work with it is ojdbc6 11.2.0.4. This keeps me stuck to SQL Developer 4.0.3. I would like to benefit from features of newer versions of SQL Developer. But they use newer driver like ojdbc8.

Is there a way to use old drivers with new versions of SQL Developer? The option to add third party JDBC drivers only work to add drivers for other databases like db2 or sql server.

I tried to delete the recent driver and replace it by an older one but SQL Developer malfunctions.

Comment: That's not supported

Comment: Is there any previous versions archive where I can download 4.x versions? Oracle site has only 20.x links and google can find a link to 3.2.2.

Comment: It would be better to put effort in upgrading that database

Comment: Maybe. But for now and old SQL Developer is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Developer version 20.2.0 on Windows 10 do:

1. Download and unzip [SQL Developer version 20.2.0](https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.2.0.175.1842-x64.zip)
2. Download and unzip [Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.4.0](https://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/instantclient/11204/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip)
3. Configure SQL Developer to use above instant client:

   - Tools > Preferences... > Database > Advanced
   - Mark "Use Oracle Client" > Configure...
   - In "Client Type" select "Instant Client"
   - In "Client Location" point to where you unziped instant client
   - Click "Test...". The log panel should show something like

   > Testing loading Oracle JDBC driver ... OK

   > Testing checking Oracle JDBC driver version ... OK

   - OK > restart SQL Developer

   [image]
4. Configure connection:

   - Just create a normal connection
   - In "Advanced" tab add the key `oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion` with value `false`. This avoids

   > ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

   > ORA-01882: timezone region  not found

   [image]

This procedure enables you to use a more recent SQL Developer version with an old Oracle 9i r2 without hanging on connect or getting

> ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

every time you click something.