# How to connect to Oracle9i with SQLDeveloper 21?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to connect to an old Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.4.0 database with SQLDeveloper 21.4.3 and I followed this answer [How to change default JDBC driver of Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410831/how-to-change-default-jdbc-driver-of-oracle-sql-developer/66656752#66656752).

The difference is just the versions of SQLDeveloper (21 instead of 20) and Oracle Instant Client (21.3 instead of 11.2.0.4.0). In my case both are the latest ones.
My OS is also Windows 10, 64bit.

Testing the client and connection as described are successful. But when actually connecting to the database SQLDeveloper hangs and can only be closed by TaskManager.

I tried both connection types: simple and with user defined URL `jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.31.10.3:1521:LZH`. This URL works in other applications like SQL Workbench/J using oracle driver `ojdbc14_g.jar`.

I also tried to set this jar file in SQLDeveloper preferences as external jdbc driver. But I guess here only non oracle drivers like postgreSQL make sense, but don't know. It doesn't make a difference anyway.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect an Oracle Client version 21 to an (more than 20 years old) Oracle 9i database. See [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image]

Maybe ask Oracle support to get an older version of SQL Developer.

Comment: OK, then the problem is the Instant Client. I need at most version 11.2. And the new question is where to get it...

Comment: Instant Client is available from Oracle: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provided me a link for older
[Instant Client Versions](https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html).
Version 11.2 works fine with [SQLDeveloper 20.2](https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-20.2.0.175.1842-x64.zip).
SQLDeveloper 21 only supports client versions 19 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you're probably looking for but I managed to connect via Toad for Oracle with no issues.

I did switch to 32 bit Instant client 11gR2 and still had issues connecting to Oracle 9, but under 'test' within properties worked fine but hung when trying to connect - so Toad for Oracle was the only solution that worked